# Ferrite underlay impact on chip antenna performance

Tags: pcb-design, antenna, ferrite, lora

I'm designing a small wireless chargeable IoT device which also has TX/RX in subGhz frequency (LoRa). The idea is to stack everything on top of each other starting with charger RX coil, then ferrite underlay, then battery and PCB with chip antenna on top of it. While the RF channel is a challenge by itself in this situation, I realised that ferrite presence most likely will have an impact, and I'm trying to understand if it could be used for a benefit; or the presence of ferrite in near proximity to chip antenna will make it pretty much useless. This is rather a theoretical question or maybe someone had an experience with such composition and would tell straight away this is dead idea or worth going forward.

Comment: Ferrite sheet/parts will be a significant attenuator at hundreds of MHz. Not saying it won't work but I'd be thinking about having the comms antenna at the top and above the ferrite.

Comment: Thanks for the note! It's unavoidable to have a ferrite so that the wireless charger coil is properly screened and TX side wouldn't choke on having unscreened parts above TX coil. My only chance is to have enough clearance between the ferrite and antenna, but this is 5mm max. Also, most of the ferrite will be behind the battery and potentially can be screened by metal piece working as the ground plane, too. So I guess the only way to know which side the ferrite will play is to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have received actual samples to experiment with I run a few tests and, from the practical point of view, I can see it is not having that major impact on antennae properties comparing to the battery or any other metal object in proximity. Please note, that I'm dealing with "chip" antennae and, therefore, it may have a rather different outcome for any other type of antenna.